# convert a perl6 grammar to perl5

Tags: perl

I am converting a Perl6 grammar to Perl5. Perl5 code below is not working, i'm using Regexp::Grammars module. Please help me with a working example.

I got this error on posting - It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details. so i'm repeating it to add some text

perl6 code

```
my $program = 'my $x = 23; say $x;';

grammar G {
  rule TOP {
    <statement>* %% ';'
  }
  rule statement {
    | <variable-declaration>
    | <function-call>
  }
  rule variable-declaration {
    'my' <variable-name> '=' <value>
  }
  token variable-name {
    '$' <alpha>+
  }
  token value {
    <digit>+
  }
  rule function-call {
    <function-name> <variable-name>
  }
  token function-name {
    'say'
  }
}

say G.parse($program);
```

perl5 code

```
my $text = q[my $x = 23; say $x;];

my $parser = qr {
    <nocontext:>
    <Statements>
    <rule: Statements>    <[Statement]>* % <Separator>
    <rule: Statement>     <Var-Decl> | <Fun-Call>
    <rule: Var-Decl>      my <Var-Name> = <Value>
    <rule: Var-Name>      $ [a-zA-z]+
    <token: Value>        \d+
    <rule: Fun-Call>      <Fun-Name> <Var-Name>
    <token: Fun-Name>     say
    <token: Separator>    ;
}xms;

if( $text =~ $parser ) {
    my %res = %/;
    print Dumper \%res;
}
```

Comment: You might try [use re 'debug'](https://perldoc.pl/re#'debug'-mode) or [Regexp::Debugger](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Debugger) to narrow down the problem.

Comment: `$ [a-zA-z]+` should probably be `\$ [a-zA-Z_]\w*` with uppercase Z, backslash before `$` since it's a metacharacter in regexes and allowing for `_` and 0-9 in variable names. Remove `-` from `<Var-Decl>` and others and of course `use Regexp::Grammars;` and `use Data::Dumper;`.

Answer (score 4):

`<debug: on>`  is very helpful. after few changes it is working

perl5 code

```
my $text = q[my $x = 23; say $x;];

my $parser = qr {
    <nocontext:>
    #<debug: on>
    <Statements>
    <rule: Statements>    <[Statement]>+ % <Separator>
    <rule: Statement>     <VarDecl> | <FunCall>
    <rule: VarDecl>       my <VarName> = <Value>
    <rule: VarName>       \$ [a-zA-Z]+
    <token: Value>        \d+
    <rule: FunCall>       <FunName> <VarName>
    <token: FunName>      say
    <token: Separator>    ;
}xms;


if( $text =~ $parser ) {
    my %res = %/;
    print Dumper \%res;
}
```